# Css multiple background images with margin

Tags: css, background-image

i'm trying to use 2 background images on a div, im using theese style for this

```
  background:url(../images/bg1.png),url(../images/bg2.png);
```

but all images are like position absolute, they are on each other so i use

```
  background-position:0px 0px,40px 0px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat,no-repeat;
```

when i try this 2. background dissapears, how can i fix this?

Comment: When you say it 'disappears' - how wide is the element? More than 40px I guess? It's possible that setting the background images with a `background-image` attribute (instead of the shortcut `background`) might fix it.

Comment: In jsfiddle this seems to work with background or background-image (in Firefox and Safari, anyway): http://jsfiddle.net/SRDks/. What browser are you looking in?

Comment: lol yes, my bad. it's about background image size. Thanks.

Comment: @Malixxi As in the question was wrong, or you've just fixed it?

Comment: bg1 was wider than 40px, i tought it was not. when i read your comment i look it again then i see my mistake.

Comment: +1 for bringing the ability to have multiple background images on one element to my attention! Awesomeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, seems that the container is too narrow. It's 'disappearing' because the position is wider than the element.

Answer (score -1):

I could be wrong, but I didn't know multiple background is allowed.

Since I'm assuming that you're using translucent png's, why don't just put them in 2 divs and wrap one inside another?

Comment: Multiple background images are allowed, so using a non-semantic `<div/>` is unnecessary.